# I can't add data to the database through form

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have been working on making a website in which people can post the evaluation of the restaurant they visited. I want users to post data through a form, but I can't make a form page work as I imagined. To speak the detail, the data put in the form isn't added to the database. Please tell me why the system doesn't work. I can't find the data I typed in the form on admin page and "Tabelog/list.html".

The function named "form" is the one trying to show the form on the page and save data to the database.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

stars = [
    (1,"☆"),
    (2,"☆☆"),
    (3,"☆☆☆"),
    (4,"☆☆☆☆"),
    (5,"☆☆☆☆☆")
]

# Create your models here.
class Tabelog(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField("店名",max_length = 124)
    evaluation = models.IntegerField("評価",choices = stars)
    comment = models.TextField("口コミ")

    def outline(self):
        return self.comment[:10]

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{},{},{}".format(self.store_name,self.evaluation,self.comment[:10]))
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from Tabelog.models import Tabelog

class CreateTabelogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tabelog
        fields = "__all__"
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from Tabelog import views

app_name = "Tabelog"

urlpatterns = [
    path("lp/", views.lp,name="lp"),
    path("list/",views.list,name="list"),
    path("detail/<str:store_name>",views.detail,name="detail"),
    path("form/",views.form,name="form")
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Tabelog.models import Tabelog
from Tabelog.forms import CreateTabelogForm
# Create your views here.
def lp(request):
    return render(request,"Tabelog/lp.html")

def list(request):
    info = Tabelog.objects.all()
    context = {
        "info":info,
    }
    return render(request,"Tabelog/list.html",context)

def detail(request,store_name):
    detail = Tabelog.objects.get(store_name = store_name)
    context = {
        "detail":detail,
    }
    return render(request,"Tabelog/detail.html",context)

def form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateTabelogForm()
        context = {
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)

    else:
        form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "post" and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("Tabelog:list")

        else:
            form = CreateTabelogForm()
            context = {
                "form":form
            }
            return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Tabelog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        Welcome to Tabelog!
      </header>
      <main>
        {% block content%}
        {% endblock %}
      </main>
      <footer>Thank you for providing information!</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'Tabelog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT!</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'Tabelog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for contents in info%}
<article class="store">
  <h1> <a href="{% url 'Tabelog:detail' contents.store_name %}">{{contents.store_name}}</a></h1>
  <h2>{{contents.get_stars_display}}</h2>
  <span>{{contents.outline}}</span>
</article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo here. You have used `request.method=="post"`, it should `request.method == "POST"`. To be honest, that check is reduandent, so you should remove it.

```
def form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateTabelogForm()
        context = {
            "form":form
        }
        return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)

    else:
        form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "post" and form.is_valid():
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           # remove this code
```

A refactored version of that code:

```
def form(request):
    form = CreateTabelogForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect("Tabelog:list")
     context = {
        "form":form
     }
     return render(request,"Tabelog/form.html",context)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could solve the problem finally!